# why does this Dynamic Sql Statement fail?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is no any problem:

```
select COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,IS_NULLABLE 
from [AdventureWorks2012].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name='employee';
```

But, when it moved to a dynamic statement, it always fail:

```
begin
DECLARE @sqlstatement VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TableName varchar(max)='employee';

set @sqlstatement='select COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,IS_NULLABLE
from [AdventureWorks2012].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name='+@TableName;
print (@sqlstatement);
EXECUTE(@sqlstatement);

end
```

error says:Invalid column name 'employee'

Comment: One of the best ways to debug dynamic SQL problems is to print the string out, copy the output from the print statement into another query window and look it over there.  We tend to rely on intellesence and the color coding the SSMS uses more than you might think.  Had you done this you would have probably noticed the lack of quotes around your employee name pretty quickly.

Answer (score 9):

you should wrap it with single quotes since column `table_name` is string,

```
set @sqlstatement='select COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,IS_NULLABLE
from [AdventureWorks2012].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name='''+@TableName+'''';
```

Comment: Thanks.I totally mixed @sqlstatement string with a string in statement.:(

Answer (score 2):

Using `sys.sp_executesql` more desirable to executing dynamic SQL, so try this one -

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME = 'Employee';

SELECT @SQL = '
USE [AdventureWorks2012];
SELECT 
      COLUMN_NAME = c.name
    , DATA_TYPE = TYPE_NAME(c.user_type_id)
    , CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = c.max_length
    , IS_NULLABLE = c.is_nullable
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.objects o ON c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
WHERE o.name = ''' + @TableName + '''';

PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```